# Group by week and consider Saturday as start day of the week

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I want to query my postgresql data and group the results by week, so I'm using the following query:

```
select
   date_trunc ('week', date_column) as week,
   sum (orders) as orders_count
from database
group by week
```

But it uses Monday as start day of the week, while I want my weeks to be like 'Saturday -> Friday'. How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 1):

Just subtract two days, and you land on saturday:

```
select
   date_trunc('week', date_column)::date - 2 as week,
   sum (orders) as orders_count
from the_table
group by week
```

Comment: but this just changes the label of the x-axis and the sum values are the same as my query.

Comment: Yes. saeed right. Found the actual solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just offset by two days, as follows:

```
select
   date_trunc ('week', date_column + interval '2 days') - interval '2 days' as week,
   sum (orders) as orders_count
from database
group by week
```